# Element is only read as undefined when I try to assign it a variable?

Tags: javascript

My script:

```
    window.onload = addAutoplay();
    var videoLocation  = document.getElementById("home-vide");
    function addAutoplay() {
        if(window.innerWidth >992){
            videoLocation.setAttribute("autoplay","");
      };
    }
```

Is giving the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')
    at addAutoplay ((index):362:18)
    at (index):358:18
```

When I try to debug this in the console, I can see that document.getElementById("home-vide"); correctly grabs the video, but trying to assign it to a variable results in undefined. Not sure why this is?

[image]

Comment: Put `var videoLocation  = document.getElementById("home-vide");` inside `addAutoPlay`.

Comment: `window.onload = addAutoplay();` should be `window.onload = addAutoplay;`